# Passing an event up from a child element to a great-grandfather

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm just getting familiar with React Native.  Using a setup like this, I'm able to pass an even up from a child to its parent:

Child:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.props.click("Cool.")}}>
```

Parent:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.click = this.click.bind(this)
}

click(c) {
  console.log(c) // "Cool."
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Child click={this.click}>
    </View>
  }
}
```

However, if I change the Parent's return to:

```
<View>
  <Child click={this.props.click}>
</View>
```

Then use a Grandfather component:

```
<View>
  <Parent click={this.click}>
</View>
```

I'm not getting the click event, but an error `"_this2.props.click is not a function"`  Changing the child element to `<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.click}>` seems to prevent the event from being handled.

Ultimately, I'd like to have a child element trigger an event handler at the Great-Grandfather level to modify the state at the root level and cascade the changes downward.

Comment: You bind the `click` function in your `parent` but expect the grandfather to know it? If you want the action to be called in your `grandfather` you should bind the function there and pass it down the generations

Comment: @Nocebo Can you expand on this?  On the child component, I'm using `onPress={() => {this.props.click("Cool.")}}>` which passes the event up to the parent via this.props.  Then in the parent, I'm using `click={this.props.click}` which I would think would pass it up another generation, where I would then have the bound `click={this.click.bind(this)}`

Comment: oh then your description was a little bit confusing. You said "Parent:" and I thought your `parent component` follows now. But in reality that was actually your `grandparent` and `<Child/>` was your actual `Parent` component. You might want to change the label of your component then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the child's methods using `ref`. you can see the document of this in [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). A simple example of using `ref` is like below:

```
class Child extends Component {
  open = () => {
    this.props.setVisible(true)
  }

  render () { 
    <View ref={this.props.refFunc}>
      ...
    </View>
  }
}

class Parent extends Component {
  _ref = (e) => { this._child = e }

  runFunction = () => {
    this._child.open(); // you can use the open function of child here
  }

  render () { 
    ...
    <Child refFunc={this._ref}>
    ...
  }
}
```

And when you want to modify a parent from a child you should define a function and pass it into the child component as a `prop` and use it on a event like `onPress` in child component. To do achieve this the sample code would be like this:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  state = {someState: value}

  changeStateValue = (val) => {
    this.setState({someState: val})
  }

  render () { 
    ...
    <Child changeState={this.changeStateValue}>
    ...
  }
}

class Child extends Component {

  changeParentState = (val) => () => {
    this.props.changeState(val)
  }

  render () { 
    ...
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.changeParentState(value)}>
    ...
    </TouchableHighlight>
    ...
  }
}
```

In this way you can access a parent state from child component.

Comment: This would allow me to use a child's function (eg. Open) from a Parent, whereas I would like to have a child modify a Parent's, Parent's Parent state when that child receives an event like `onPress()`

Comment: That's very similar to what I'm using in my first example, passing an event up from a child to a parent.  Once I attempt to pass up to the parent's parent (on the way to the parent's parent's parent), it no longer executes.

Comment: you can use this method to change the state of your parent's parent. I have used this method to change the state of parent of parent of a child by child component and it works properly.

Comment: if you like you can update your question with you code that i can help you better.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as answered but post a more concise follow up.  Thanks for helping me walk through this.

Comment: New thread -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46161400/referencing-a-parents-event-handler-within-the-render-block