# Referencing a parent's event handler within the render() block

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a child Icon element with an `onPress()` event handler:

```
render() {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.press}>
  )
}
```

This child's IconWrapper parent component is passing down the press function with:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Icon press={this.props.press} />
      <Icon press={this.props.press} />
      <Icon press={this.props.press} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Then, I'm rendering the parent IconWrapper component from the grandparent with:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <IconWrapper press={this.press} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

The IconWrapper `press` function isn't propagating down to the Icon.  I believe I need to attach this function to the outer View component, then use the View as a reference with something like:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View ref="outerView" press={this.props.press}>
      <Icon press={this.refs.outerView.press} />
      <Icon press={this.refs.outerView.press} />
      <Icon press={this.refs.outerView.press} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

or maybe:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View ref="outerView">
      <Icon press={this.refs.outerView.props.press} />
      <Icon press={this.refs.outerView.props.press} />
      <Icon press={this.refs.outerView.props.press} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

How would I go about referencing a parent's event handler within the render() block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `IconWrapper` bind the reference of the class to the function. This should work without having to use `refs`.

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <IconWrapper press={this.press.bind(this)} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Got it, that's working.  I think my problem all along was that I was initially using `click` as my property (thinking there wouldn't be any click properties in a mobile touch-driven environment)... but using `click` as a property instead of `press` seems actually to prevent the event from being picked up (without anything really showing up in the debugger.)  Having this not work from the get-go had me rethinking the inheritance model.  Cool!